# Get byte stream of headers properties IBM MQ

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I've got messages from queue by using IBM MQ. I got object MQMessage and parse it. In this way, I have byte stream of message body, also I have MQMD properties. So, how can I get this properties in byte array too?

```
//Getting MQMessage
MQQueue queue = ...
MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
queue.get(msg, options, size);

//For example this prop
String replyQueue = msg.replyToQueueName;
```

I need it, because in some cases some props don't read correctly with default "UTF-8" encoding, but it should.
So, `MQMessage.readFully(byte[] b)` only give me the message body as `byte[]`, I would like to get the message headers such as MQMD and RFH2.

Answer (score 1):

All of the MQMD properties can be accessed as:

```
byte[] correlId = msg.correlationId;
byte[] msglId = msg.messageId;
String format = msg.format;
int expiry = msg.expiry;
String replyQueue = msg.replyToQueueName;
```

There are 2 ways to deal with a JMS (aka MQRFH2) message:

- Retrieve it as a message with named properties
- Retrieve it as an MQRFH2 message

To get the JMS message as a "message with named properties", just add an MQGMO option of:

```
gmo.options += CMQC.MQGMO_PROPERTIES_IN_HANDLE;
```

Then you can retrieve any named property using a getter method.  i.e. to retrieve the string property called StackOverflow, you would do:

String someValue = msg.getStringProperty("StackOverflow")

To retrieve the JMS message as an MQRFH2, just add an MQGMO of (this is the default):

```
gmo.options += CMQC.MQGMO_PROPERTIES_FORCE_MQRFH2;
```

Then you need to pass the message to the MQRFH2 class and go from there:

```
msg.seek(0);
MQRFH2 rfh2 = new MQRFH2(msg);
String format = rfh2.getFormat();
String[] folderStrings = rfh2.getFolderStrings();
for (String folder : folderStrings)
System.out.println("Folder: "+folder);
```

Comment: Thunks a lot for your answer! Some strange case. For example I put cirillic word in "format" property of MQRFH2 header, the default charset is UTF-8 that include cirillic symbols. When I read this property in these two ways, that you mansion before, I get incorrect word. So, the question is, how to get headers properties with choosing charset, like getting message body? Or some way to get "format" property in byte[], not in String format.